# Count max depending on two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to get the max number of counts and its corresponding year for movies and series. The df is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
     [
       ("movie", "2020", 45),
       ("movie", "2019", 37),
       ("series", "2018", 16),
       ("series", "2010", 45),
    ],
columns=("type", "year", "count"),
 )
```

What I've tried:

```
df[df['type'] == "series"].max()
df[df['type'] == "movie"].max()
```

However this does not seem to work well as it returns the max year and max count. As for example, for the series one, it will return:

```
type     series
year       2018
count        45
dtype: object
```

and it should return:

```
type     series
year       2010
count        45
dtype: object
```

How should I build my query so it returns the highest count with its corresponding year?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try sort and drop duplicates:

```
df.sort_values('count').drop_duplicates('type', keep='last')
```

Output:

```
     type  year  count
0   movie  2020     45
3  series  2010     45
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `idxmax`

```
out = df.loc[df.groupby('type')['count'].idxmax()]
Out[200]: 
     type  year  count
0   movie  2020     45
3  series  2010     45
```